# Unity transform.rotation not giving real value

Tags: unity, 2d, rotation, transformation

i confused , when the object is at **0 rotation ( not rotated yet )**  , it giving real value ( **0** ) , but when the object is **rotated 180 degree** , transform.rotation is giving false value ( **1** ) , this is the screenshot :

[image: Faded - By Alan Walker , anyway have you play game like Demonophobia ? or Ib ? or Mad Father ?]

If the picture is not clear enough , go here https://i.stack.imgur.com/miWIE.png .

Then this is my script that debugged the code and rotate the object :

```
void RotateFlip() {
    GameObject databasegameobject = GameObject.Find ("database");
    database databasechange = databasegameobject.GetComponent<database>();
    Debug.Log ("current object rotation is " + theiconarrow.transform.rotation.z + " degree ");
    if (databasechange.pengertianmenustate == 2) {
        if (theiconarrow.transform.rotation.z == 0 ) {
            theiconarrow.transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (theiconarrow.transform.rotation.x, theiconarrow.transform.rotation.y, 180), Space.World);
        }

    }

    if (databasechange.pengertianmenustate == 1) {
        if (theiconarrow.transform.rotation.z == 180) {
            theiconarrow.transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (theiconarrow.transform.rotation.x, theiconarrow.transform.rotation.y, 180), Space.World);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this thing happened , is this a kind of bug or what ?

**I am sorry if this already asked somewhere , but i just don't know how to find it at search engine ( neither here ) .**

Extra question ( optional ) : is there any application to build app with easy coding and not an game engine ?

Comment: Unity stores rotations as quaternions ([see the doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html)) with every component in the range -1.0 to 1.0 - see [this question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/645903/please-explain-quaternions.html) for more details

Comment: then what should i use to get the current rotation ?

Comment: As suggested in the answer you could use [`transform.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) instead. Or learn how to work with quaternions - both are valid options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity, like many 3D softwares uses [Quaternions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html) to deal with rotation (prevent the [Gimbal Lock problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)). You get a quaternion when you call `theiconarrow.transform.rotation` (a quaternion is represented by 4 values : x, y, z, w, but are not really the angles around the 3 axis with an additional value).

However, because quaternions are not easily readable by humans, the inspector shows you the euler angles (pitch, yaw, roll) of the rotation (which *are* the angles around the 3 unit axis). In your code, you can get the euler angles by calling : `theiconarrow.transform.eulerAngles`.

Comment: thanks ! :) **the unity documentation are just too bad**

Comment: i had another problem , the value of quarternions are increasing each rotated from 180 , back to zero then back to 180 again , like 1.E-50 then 2.E-525 , and just keep increasing , do you know why ?

Comment: I highly advise you to not deal with the direct values of the quaternions. Use the euler angles if you want to make comparisons, and the [Quaternions static functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) to manipulate a quaternion (rotate, ...)

Comment: well i guess i will just the power of **variable** instead those thing :P